# Adding pointer on rollover in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: javascript, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I am starting to use Adobe Animate CC to make a 300x250 banner. I added this code from the code snippet section to my movieclip **EDIT** **using HTML5 Canvas option.**

```
this.bg_clickTag.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
}

var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.bg_clickTag.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);

function fl_MouseOverHandler()
{

    //this.bg_clickTag.cursor = "pointer";
    //bg_clickTag.cursor = "pointer";
    //cursor = "pointer";
    //alert("Moused over");

}
```

I get the click though just fine, the issue I am having is the the cursor/pointer is not changing once I mouse over.

I am able to get the cursor/pointer change if I change the movieclip to a button, but I would rather keep it a movieclip.

Seems like a easy fix just having trouble combining my previous flash experience and Javascript.

thanks!

Comment: Try putting `bg_clickTag.cursor = "pointer"` at the top of the code you posted, outside the `mouseover` handler.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that did the trick.

`this.mc_bg_clickTag.cursor = "pointer";
this.mc_bg_clickTag.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage() {
 window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
  
}

var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);`

Comment: That's good to know. I'll convert to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `cursor = "pointer"` line outside the `mouseover` handler. When you set the `cursor` it will only show the cursor when the mouse is over the object:

```
this.bg_clickTag.cursor = "pointer";
this.bg_clickTag.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
}

var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
```